# Where can I find Approval Category IDs for Gerrit hooks?

Tags: hook, gerrit

I'm authoring a [tiny utility lib](https://github.com/nlsdfnbch/gerrit-hooks) to supply argument parsers for gerrit hooks, but have stumbled upon a flag that I can't figure out.

The comment-added hook supports `--<approval-category-id>` flags, but I am not sure about where to find the IDs.
I'm quite confident that they relate to the Review labels available (verify, reviewed), but their documentation mentions nothing about an ID.

Anyone know where I can find these ?

Hook flag documentation [here](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/hooks/+/HEAD/src/main/resources/Documentation/hooks.md#comment_added)
Gerrit Review label documentation [here](https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.15.3/config-labels.html#label_Code-Review)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

approval-category-id is the same as the "Review labels" defined [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-labels.html). They can be "Code-Review", "Verified" or any other you have [customized](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-labels.html#label_custom).

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of the hooks is a bit lacking.  I've opened an issue upstream to improve this:

[Hooks plugin's documentation lacks enough information about the hook parameters](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=9701)